# urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request from trying to get a set of images

Tags: python

I was trying to get a set of images for a dataset to train tiny-yolo on so I followed this tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lg4T9iJkwhE&index=5&list=PLX-LrBk6h3wSGvuTnxB2Kj358XfctL4BM

The first file that was written in the tutorial goes like this:

```
import os
import urllib.request as ulib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
import json

url_a = 'https://www.google.com/search?ei=1m7NWePfFYaGmQG51q7IBg&hl=en&q={}'
url_b = '\&tbm=isch&ved=0ahUKEwjjovnD7sjWAhUGQyYKHTmrC2kQuT0I7gEoAQ&start={}'
url_c = '\&yv=2&vet=10ahUKEwjjovnD7sjWAhUGQyYKHTmrC2kQuT0I7gEoAQ.1m7NWePfFYaGmQG51q7IBg'
url_d = '\.i&ijn=1&asearch=ichunk&async=_id:rg_s,_pms:s'
url_base = ''.join((url_a, url_b, url_c, url_d))

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36'}


def get_links(search_name):
    search_name = search_name.replace(' ', '+')
    url = url_base.format(search_name, 0)
    request = ulib.Request(url, None, headers)
    json_string = ulib.urlopen(request).read()
    page = json.loads(json_string)
    new_soup = Soup(page[1][1], 'lxml')
    images = new_soup.find_all('img')
    links = [image['src'] for image in images]
    return links


def save_images(links, search_name):
    directory = search_name.replace(' ', '_')
    if not os.path.isdir(directory):
        os.mkdir(directory)

    for i, link in enumerate(links):
        savepath = os.path.join(directory, '{:06}.png'.format(i))
        ulib.urlretrieve(link, savepath)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    search_name = 'my search query'
    links = get_links(search_name)
    save_images(links, search_name)
```

The only thing I changed was the headers variable since my User-agent is different than the guy in the tutorial's one.

To my supprise the script returned this error

```
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Those backslashes don't look like they belong in the URL - why do you think you need them?

Comment: It looks like `url_a` and `url_b` might need to be formatted strings; you have the curly braces `{}` used in formatting but haven't put a value there. With URLs for queries like these, you probably want to put some sort of value there. Also, why the backslashes? Backslahses in URLs are an incorrect form (source: https://zzz.buzz/2017/09/19/forward-and-backslashes-in-urls/)

Answer (score 1):

The Error code itself explains the issue
you are trying to hit URL which doesn't exist.

Please correct your URL. [image]

URL:- `https://www.google.com/search?ei=1m7NWePfFYaGmQG51q7IBg&hl=en&q=my+search+query\\&tbm=isch&ved=0ahUKEwjjovnD7sjWAhUGQyYKHTmrC2kQuT0I7gEoAQ&start=0\\&yv=2&vet=10ahUKEwjjovnD7sjWAhUGQyYKHTmrC2kQuT0I7gEoAQ.1m7NWePfFYaGmQG51q7IBg\\.i&ijn=1&asearch=ichunk&async=_id:rg_s,_pms:s%27`

Try on Browser, see what you get.